# ElasticSearch Script Score Using Field Value

Tags: elasticsearch

**ElasticSearch 1.2.1**

I am trying to query documents using weighted tags.

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/test'

curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/thing/_mapping' - '{
    "thing": {
        "properties": {
            "tags": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                        "name": { "type": "string" },
                        "weight": { "type": "integer" }
                }
            }
        }
    }}'
```

Adding a document:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/thing/1', -d '{
    "tags": [
        { "name": "a", "weight": 2 }
    ]
}'
```

Now I am searching for documents having a tag `a` and boost the score based on the `weight`.

*Note:* to run these examples you have to enable dynamic scripting in ElasticSearch: add `script.disable_dynamic: false` to `elasticsearch.yml`

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/test/thing/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "boost_mode": "replace",
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "functions": [
            {
              "filter": {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "tags",
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "tags.name": "a"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "script_score": {
                "script": "doc.weight.value"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}'
```

The document is found, as expected, however the score is `0`. It seems as if the property `doc.weight` was empty.

Let's test this by replacing the script with `doc.weight.empty ? 50 : 100`. The hit now has a score of `50` indicating that the field `doc.weight` is empty. It is *found* though, because using a non-existant field name (e.g. `doc.foobar`) gives an error.

Background: The `match_all` part would be replaced by a real query. I want to use the tags to boost results matching the tags before the ones not matching the tags.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure `doc.weight` is a valid syntax for accessing field values? I only know the `doc['weight'].value` syntax as mentioned [in the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields).

Comment: I suppose you should try doc['tags.weight'].value

Comment: @Thorsten the two notations are equivalent because the document is evaluated as a Map. I've tried either.